# How to implement try & catch in smaryPy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

How do we implement following solidity code in smartPy.

```
try this.checkAddress(to) {
    sendResponseMessage(
                        Types.ServiceType.REPONSE_HANDLE_SERVICE,
                        _from,
                        _sn,
                        "",
                        RC_OK
                    );
     return;
} 
catch Error(string memory _err) {
                    errMsg = _err;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to catch exceptions on Tezos.

SmartPy (and Michelson, the language into which it is compiled) is using Some/None system, also known as option.

The `sp.contract(<type>, <address>, <entrypoint>)` instruction returns an option of a contract.

It returns `None` if no contract with this entrypoint exists and `Some(contract)` if the contract exists.

See https://smartpy.io/docs/types/options/ for more info about options.

In general, options can be used everywhere something is supposed to return a value. None can be returned instead of an exception. Some can also return a variant with an error and a variant with the valid value if they want to return an error value.

Comment: Can you share any work around solutions on this.

Comment: I edited my answer.